# Using .Control.item to set name of combobox

Tags: vba

I have a bunch of comboboxes to set up and was trying to use a sub because of it just being a repeat function for each combobox. Each combobox will have 0 to up to 15 (just numbers) in it.
I have used this type of code before and it worked. Not sure what I am doing wrong this time.

```
'''
'Call FillInCombobox(4, CB_TSM.Name)'
' '
'Sub FillInCombobox(Num as long,CB_Name as String)'
'Dim NameCB as Combobox'
'Dim x as Integer'
'   Set NameCB = .Controls.Item(CB_Name)'
'With NameCB'
'   .clear'
'   For x = 0 to Num'
'      NameCB.Additem x'
'   Next x'
'End with'
'End sub'
'''
```

When I step through the program it stops at 'Set NameCB = .Control.Item(CB_Name)'. And the error it has is 'Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.'

Comment: You need to use the Set statement to assign a (particular) Combobox  object to the NameCB variable (BEFORE the With NameCB block).

Comment: Spectrallnstance - I moved it and now the error "is involved or unqualified reference"

Comment: Ok, so please edit your post to show how your code currently looks.

Comment: `Set NameCB = .Controls.Item(CB_Name)` should probably be `Set NameCB = Me.Controls.Item(CB_Name)` or Application. You haven't specified a `With` so the *Object variable or With block variable is not set.*

Comment: Thank you Jeremy Thompson than work. You are a big help. Can you tell me why just adding "Me." made it work?